# Ending the Onscreenclick() command in Python Turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have been looking around for a while for a solution, but no cigar...
In my CS class we have been assigned to create a Dots and Boards game in Python Turtle and I am trying to be able to use onscreenclick() to detect region of click and to move forward in the games progress (i.e Title screen).
My code-

```
def initial():
    color("white")
    write("Dots and Boxes", align = "center", font = ("Arial", 100))
    penup()
    setpos(0,-125)
    pendown()
    write("Want to play?", align = "center", font = ("Arial", 50))
    penup()
    setpos(0,350)
    pendown()
    write("(Click to begin)", align = "center", font = ("Arial", 50))
    onscreenclick(main)

def start():
    print("Click on a red dot to begin!(Choose wisely, this will be your turn): ")


def main(x,y):
    clear()
    board()
    start()

initial()
```

This is too create the title screen and to use the command to progress, the issue is that the command won't end so with each click, the main board is redrawn!
Thanks for the help!
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

To disable `onscreenclick(main)` simply do `onscreenclick(None)` (possibly inside `main()`) and then redo `onscreenclick(main)` when you want that functionality again.